# Sessions and session_create_id() with Prefix and strict mode config set to on

Tags: php, session

My objective is to create a more secure session id.I am attempting to prefix a sha1 hash on to the existing Session, Though my concern now is that in order to do this I have to shut strict mode off is there a way to do this while keeping strict mode on?

```
 function sess_regenration(){
      if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){

        //CreateRandomStringForPrefix
        $RandomizerForPreFix = str_split("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        shuffle($RandomizerForPreFix);
        $EmptyStringToAppenRandomizer = '';

foreach($RandomizerForPreFix as $Element ){
         $EmptyStringToAppenRandomizer .= $Element;
       }

        //HashShuffle
        $HashedValue = sha1($Element);
        //CreateNewSessionIdWithPrefix
        ini_set('session.use_strict_mode',0);
        $CreatedId = session_create_id($HashedValue);
        session_id($CreatedId);
        //StartSession
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name'] = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        echo session_id();
      }

    }


        sess_regenration();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do it. There's a setting in php.ini called session.hash_function which accepts a numerical value. To get the value that you need, run the hash_algos() function in a script on its own. That will give you an array of all hashing algorithms available. Say it had sha1 as the fourth value in the array, you'd take it's index in the array (3) and give that to session.hash_function as the one to use so that would read in the example:

```
session.hash_function 3
```

Don't forget to reboot the server after having made the change to php.ini

You might want to write a small bit of code to run before session_start() is called to check the index of sha1 in the array returned by hash_algos() and set the value for session.hash_function via ini_set()

Comment: would you recommend running everything from a script rather than changing the settings in the php.ini file?

Comment: Doing it from the script would give you a little flexibility as you wouldn't have to edit the php.ini file, every time either you use a new server, or the list of available algorithms changes